# How to get the `fb:explicitly_shared` permission on facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-permissions

I have an app where the user can post his activity after a workout. In order for that to properly appear on the users timeline, I need the `fb:explicitly_shared` permission. But I just can't see where to get it!!! I've seen screenshots like [image] but I just have no idea on where to find that dialog in the developer-dashboard on Facebook. I already have the `publish_action` permission and wrote about the `fb:explicitly_shared` in the comments when I requested it, but it's still not working and the `FBSDKShareAPI` complains about the missing permission.

Can anybody tell me where I can request that permission?!? In my iOS Code I currently request `publish_actions`. The explicitly shared can't be requested, cause then the FB-SDK crashes, telling that it's not possible to request it.

Comment: It’s not a “permission”, it is a capability. And you find it in the settings of your OG action type.

Comment: Ah... nice... I see... If you retype your answer as weal answer, I'd accept it so you can receive your reputation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not a “permission”, it is a capability.

And you find it in the settings of your OG action type.